# how to set image in RecyclerView using Picasso

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-volley, picasso

i'm using Picasso to get image and show in recyclerview but i don't know how to get and set image in recyclerview. i ready many questions on stack but i did not understand.

**here is mainActivity**

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_food__ngo_)


        var item = ArrayList<dumy_item_list>()
      var progressBar2 = findViewById<ProgressBar>(R.id.progressBar2)
        var away_recycler = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.away_recycler)
        away_recycler.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(applicationContext, 1)
        var url = "https://apps.faizeqamar.website/charity/api/organizations"
        var rq: RequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
        var sr = StringRequest(
            Request.Method.GET, url, Response.Listener { response ->
                var jsonResponse = JSONObject(response)
                var jsonArray: JSONArray = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("data")
                for (i in 0..jsonArray.length() - 1) {
                    var jsonObject: JSONObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
                    var name = jsonObject.getString("ngo_name")
                    var org_id = jsonObject.getString("ngo_id")
                    var ngo_phone = jsonObject.getString("ngo_phone")
                    AppPrefrence.ngoId = org_id
                   item.add(dumy_item_list(name,ngo_phone))
                }
                var adaptor = food_adapter(item, applicationContext)
                away_recycler.adapter = adaptor
               progressBar2?.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            },
            Response.ErrorListener { error ->
                var message: String? = null
                if (error is NetworkError) {
                    message = "Cannot connect to Internet...Please check your connection!"
                } else if (error is ServerError) {
                    message =
                        "The server could not be found. Please try again after some time!!"
                } else if (error is AuthFailureError) {
                    message = "Cannot connect to Internet...Please check your connection!"
                } else if (error is ParseError) {
                    message = "Parsing error! Please try again after some time!!"
                } else if (error is NoConnectionError) {
                    message = "Cannot connect to Internet...Please check your connection!"
                } else if (error is TimeoutError) {
                    message = "Connection TimeOut! Please check your internet connection."
                }
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext,message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            })
        rq.add(sr)
    }
```

**here is Adapter class**

```
class food_adapter(data: ArrayList<dumy_item_list>, var context: Context) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<food_adapter.viewHolder>() {
    var data: List<dumy_item_list>
    init {
        this.data = data
        this.context = context;
    }
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): food_adapter.viewHolder {

        var layout = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.dumy_item, parent, false)
        return viewHolder(layout)
    }
    override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: viewHolder, position: Int) {

        viewHolder.tv_dummy_name_donnor.setText(data[position].tv_dummy_name_donnor)
        viewHolder.tv_dummy_phone_donnor.setText(data[position].tv_dummy_phone_donnor)
        viewHolder.tv_counter.setText((position+1).toString())



        viewHolder.card.setOnClickListener {
            var intent = Intent(context, Food_Activity::class.java)
        //   intent.putExtra("name",data[position].tv_dummy_name_donnor)
        //   intent.putExtra("about",data[position].about)
            intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            startActivity(context, intent, null)
        }
    }
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return data.size
    }
    class viewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        internal var tv_dummy_name_donnor: TextView
        internal var tv_dummy_phone_donnor: TextView
        internal var img_ngo: ImageView
        internal var tv_counter: TextView
        internal var card: CardView
        init {
            tv_dummy_name_donnor = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_dummy_name_donnor)
            tv_dummy_phone_donnor = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_dummy_phone_donnor)
            img_ngo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_ngo)
            tv_counter = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_counter)
            card = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you also paste the code, of where u r setting the image in you adapter. i.e. Show your Picasso implementation

Comment: this is how i'm setting the image in adapter ... Picasso.get().load("https://apps.faizeqamar.website/charity/storage/$ngi_id").into(viewHolder.img_ngo)

Comment: but image is not displaying in recyclerView .. image View is empty

Comment: is that the entire link? Do you see any error from Picasso in your logcat?

Comment: yes this is entry link.... sir image are show in profile activity but not show in recyclerView

Comment: there is no error sir

Comment: Why is ur img_ngo an integer type? Please paste your model class in the question.

Answer (score 0):

add dependecicy
`implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'`
sync the project
and then

in onBindViewHolder

```
Picasso.get(data[position].image).load(img_ngo).error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(viewHolder.img_ngo)
```

replace `R.mipmam.ic_launcher` with default image, that is visible, if targeted image could not load in time.

and here in `data[position].image` image is the variable that you have initialised in model

let me now the result

**Edit -**
`Picasso.get().load(data[position].image).error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(viewHolder.img_ngo)` - [Thung Thang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13946668/thuan-tang)

Comment: It should be
``Picasso.get().load(data[position].image).error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(viewHolder.img_ngo)``
And don't forget to check if ``data[position].image`` is not blank to avoid crash

Comment: Sir this is my model class: class dumy_item_list( var tv_dummy_name_donnor: String? = null, var tv_dummy_phone_donnor:String?=null , var tv_counter:String?=null,var img_ngo:Int?=null ) {

}

Comment: by using this method i already get image in profile activity but i'm not able to get image in recyclerview.              Picasso.get().load("https://apps.faizeqamar.website/charity/storage/$pro_img").into(profile_image)

Comment: ```Picasso.get().load(data[position].img_ngo).error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(viewHolder.img_ngo)```
use this, and recheck that ```img_ngo``` is of ```Int``` type, it should be ```String``` as you are fetching image from URL, and URL is of string type,

Comment: Picasso.get().load("https://apps.faizeqamar.website/charity/storage/$ngi_id").error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(viewHolder.img_ngo)...sir this work for me..but this show only mipmap image not server image that we want to get..

Comment: ```Picasso.get().load(data[position].img_ngo).error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(viewHolder.img_ngo)``` 
this is not working?